# How do I get MDIMain form to get application close message before mdichild forms

Tags: delphi, windows-10, mdi, formclosing

Our application uses 'MDI' (with most of the issues fixed in TForm descedants).  In most forms if the data has been changed then it refuses to close (using closequery) and tells the user to save or cancel.  This works just fine.

But unlike other people, I would like to skip this if the Application is dying.  This could be because the user has clicked on the <kbd>X</kbd> on the MainForm.  I just want the application to die - no saving of data etc.

The problem is that the MainForm's CloseQuery fires after the all the mdichild forms'.  I have tried wm_close, wm_quit and even windproc in the MainForm.  But they do not fire in time.

When I get a formclosequery in the mdichild I have no way of knowing if that form is being killed by the user or if it is the application that is being killed.

Surely there is a simple way of doing this.  What have I missed ?

Comment: Can you show how you handle WM_CLOSE in your main form

Comment: @ken it's MS, back compat is king, works just as it always did, whisper it but my app is mdi.....

Comment: @David: Yes, I know. Did you not see the ;-) at the end?

Comment: Clicking on the `MainForm`'s X will notify the `MainForm` first, and then it notifies its child forms. If you are having trouble handling that initial notification in `WndProc()` then you are likely not handling it correctly. Please show your actual code.

Comment: This seems like a strange behavior for customers to request. Are you sure you understood them correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The explanation for this behaviour can be found in the implementation of `TCustomForm.CloseQuery`, which looks like this:

```
function TCustomForm.CloseQuery: Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if FormStyle = fsMDIForm then
  begin
    Result := False;
    for I := 0 to MDIChildCount - 1 do
      if not MDIChildren[I].CloseQuery then Exit;
  end;
  Result := True;
  if Assigned(FOnCloseQuery) then FOnCloseQuery(Self, Result);
end;
```

The code calls `CloseQuery` on each of the MDI children, which fires any `OnCloseQuery` events attached to the MDI children, and then fires the `OnCloseQuery` event for the main MDI form.

So you can take matters into your own hands by simply overriding `CloseQuery` in your main MDI form and taking steps to preempt this behaviour.

For instance, you might do this in your main form:

```
// in the form type declaration:
function CloseQuery: Boolean; override;

// in the implementation section:
function TMainForm.CloseQuery: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if Assigned(OnCloseQuery) then OnCloseQuery(Self, Result);
end;
```

Or maybe like this:

```
function TMainForm.CloseQuery: Boolean;
begin
  while MDIChildCount > 0 do
    MDIChildren[0].Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Or even:

```
function TMainForm.CloseQuery: Boolean;
begin
  Application.Halt;
end;
```